'StyledRoot' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof StyledRoot'?ts(2749)
I have a nextjs 14 app Using Typescript, app router, styled components and styled-system. I am currently experiencing 2 challnges

Most of the JSX doesn't give intellisense. There is a red squigle and when i hover over it, it gives errors similar to 'StyledRoot' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof StyledRoot'?ts(2749). In my case StyledRoot is a styled-component.
I have searcehed over the internet, people are telling me to change .ts to .tsx. The extension is aleady .tsx. Bellow is the component

"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

import useVisibility from "./useVisibility";

import Icon from "@component/icon/Icon";
import FlexBox from "@component/FlexBox";
import TextField from "@component/text-field";
import { Button, IconButton } from "@component/buttons";
import { H3, H5, H6, SemiSpan, Small, Span } from "@component/Typography";
import Spinner from "@component/Spinner";
import LoadingBar from "@component/LoadingBar";
// STYLED COMPONENT
import { StyledRoot } from "./styles";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ILoginResults, ResultsType } from "interfaces";
import { AppConst } from "@lib/app-constants";
import useLogin from "@hook/useLogin";
import { IUser } from "interfaces/iuser";

type FormType = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
};
export default function Login() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { passwordVisibility, togglePasswordVisibility } = useVisibility();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { status, user, message } = useLogin();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status && user) {
      router.push("/");
    }
  }, [status, user]);

  const initialValues: FormType = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
  };

  const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
    username: yup.string().required("Enter phone number or email"),
    password: yup.string().required("Password is required"),
  });

  const handleFormSubmit = async (values: FormType) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await signIn("credentials", {
        username: values.username,
        password: values.password,
        redirect: false,
        // callbackUrl: "/",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const { values, errors, touched, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit } =
    useFormik({
      initialValues,
      onSubmit: handleFormSubmit,
      validationSchema: formSchema,
    });

  return (
    <StyledRoot mx="auto" my="2rem" boxShadow="large" borderRadius={8}>
      <form className="content" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <H3 textAlign="center" mb="0.5rem">
          {`Welcome To ${AppConst.APP_NAME} Login Page`}
        </H3>
        {loading ? (
          <LoadingBar />
        ) : message && !status ? (
          <H6
            fontWeight="600"
            fontSize="12px"
            color={status ? "#4caf50" : "#ff0000"}
            textAlign="center"
            mb="0.5rem"
          >
            {message}
          </H6>
        ) : null}

        <TextField
          fullwidth
          mb="0.75rem"
          name="username"
          type="text"
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.username}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Enter phone or email"
          label="Email or Phone Number"
          errorText={touched.username && errors.username}
        />

        <TextField
          mb="1rem"
          fullwidth
          name="password"
          label="Password"
          autoComplete="on"
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Password"
          value={values.password}
          errorText={touched.password && errors.password}
          type={passwordVisibility ? "text" : "password"}
          endAdornment={
            <IconButton
              p="0.25rem"
              mr="0.25rem"
              type="button"
              onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
              color={passwordVisibility ? "gray.700" : "gray.600"}
            >
              <Icon variant="small" defaultcolor="currentColor">
                {passwordVisibility ? "eye-alt" : "eye"}
              </Icon>
            </IconButton>
          }
        />

        <Button
          mb="1.65rem"
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          type="submit"
          fullwidth
          disabled={loading}
        >
          Login
        </Button>
      </form>

      <FlexBox justifyContent="center" bg="gray.200" py="10px">
        <SemiSpan>Don't have account?</SemiSpan>
        <Link href="/signup">
          <H6 ml="0.5rem" borderBottom="1px solid" borderColor="gray.900">
            Signup here
          </H6>
        </Link>
      </FlexBox>

      <FlexBox justifyContent="center" bg="gray.200" py="10px">
        <SemiSpan>Forgot your password?</SemiSpan>
        <Link href="/">
          <H6 ml="0.5rem" borderBottom="1px solid" borderColor="gray.900">
            Go Home
          </H6>
        </Link>
      </FlexBox>
    </StyledRoot>
  );
}



The second issue is, I get Typescript error from styled-system. Argument of type 'CssFunctionReturnType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Styles<Substitute<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>, Props>>'.

Bellow is the component
"use client";

import {
  color,
  space,
  border,
  layout,
  shadow,
  compose,
  variant,
  ColorProps,
  SpaceProps,
  BorderProps,
  BackgroundProps,
} from "styled-system";
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import systemCss from "@styled-system/css";
import { isValidProp } from "@utils/utils";

// ==============================================================
interface IconButtonProps {
  size?: "small" | "medium" | "large" | "none";
  variant?: "text" | "outlined" | "contained";
  color?: "primary" | "secondary" | "error" | "default" | string;
}

type Props = ColorProps &
  BackgroundProps &
  BorderProps &
  SpaceProps &
  IconButtonProps;
// ==============================================================

const StyledIconButton = styled.button.withConfig({
  shouldForwardProp: (prop: string) => isValidProp(prop),
})<Props>(
  systemCss({
    flex: "0 0 auto",
    border: "none",
    outline: "none",
    lineHeight: 1,
    cursor: "pointer",
    textAlign: "center",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    padding: "1rem",
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: "inherit",
    bg: "body.paper",
    "&:hover": { bg: "gray.200" },
    transition: "all 150ms ease-in-out",
    "&:disabled": { bg: "text.disabled", color: "text.muted" },
  }),
  (props) =>
    variant({
      prop: "variant",
      variants: {
        text: { border: "none", color: `${props.color}.main` },
        outlined: {
          color: `${props.color}.main`,
          border: "2px solid",
          borderColor: `${props.color}.main`,
          "&:focus": {
            boxShadow: `0px 1px 4px 0px ${
              props.theme.colors[props.color as any]?.main
            }`,
          },
        },
        contained: {
          border: "none",
          bg: `${props.color}.main`,
          color: `${props.color}.text`,
          "&:hover": { bg: `${props.color}.main` },
          "&:focus": {
            boxShadow: `0px 1px 4px 0px ${
              props.theme.colors[props.color as any]?.main
            }`,
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  variant({
    prop: "size",
    variants: {
      medium: { padding: "1rem" },
      large: { padding: "1.25rem" },
      small: { padding: "0.75rem" },
    },
  }),
  compose(color, layout, space, border, shadow)
);

// ==============================================================
interface BtnProps extends Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  as?: string | React.ComponentType<any>;
}
// ==============================================================

const IconButton = forwardRef<
  HTMLButtonElement,
  BtnProps & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
>(({ children, size = "small", ...props }, ref) => {
  return (
    <StyledIconButton ref={ref} size={size} {...props}>
      {children}
    </StyledIconButton>
  );
});

export default IconButton;


I have changed the file extension to .tsx, I also tried to update node version to version 20.12.2 but still it did not work.
I shared the code with a colleague but he says it works well for him. Could it be a VS code editor configuration issue? Can someone help me sort the error?
